# Eliminate one of the columns from pivot_table for changing the grouping logic

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have this `dataframe`:

```
df =
GROUP  HOUR  TOTAL_SERVICE_TIME  TOTAL_WAIT_TIME  IS_EVALUATED  IS_NEGATIVE_GRADE
AAA    7     24                  32               0             0
AAA    7     23                  30               1             0
AAA    8     25                  31               1             1
BBB    7     26                  33               1             0
BBB    8     27                  31               1             0
```

I want to adapt the below-given code to grouping the data only by `GROUP`. I don't want to use the column `HOUR`. I wonder if I can use `pivot_table` without `HOUR`, so that the data is grouped only by `GROUP`, while ignoring `HOUR`?

```
piv_df = df.pivot_table(index='GROUP', columns='HOUR', fill_value=0).stack()
avg_tot = piv_df[['TOTAL_SERVICE_TIME', 'TOTAL_WAIT_TIME']].add_prefix("AVG_")
avg_pct1 = piv_df['IS_EVALUATED'].mul(100).astype(int)
avg_pct2 = piv_df['IS_NEGATIVE_GRADE'].mul(100).astype(int)
fresult = avg_tot.join(avg_pct1.to_frame("AVG_PERCENT_EVAL_1")).join(avg_pct2.to_frame("AVG_PERCENT_NEGATIVE")).reset_index()
```

Comment: ***data pls!***

Comment: @piRSquared: Ok, one moment. I thought that this question might not require the data.

Comment: @piRSquared: I posted the data.

Comment: It might not... often questions don't.  ***However***, it helps those of us who answer questions cut through the confusion.  Without it, I have to think too much to figure out what you're trying to do.  If I run into problems, I have to figure out if it's because I made incorrect assumptions about the data.  So, maybe it is needed, maybe its not.  But if you want to maximize the chances of having your questions answered... best to provide it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without `columns='Hour'`, you no longer need to `stack`

```
piv_df = df.pivot_table(index='GROUP', fill_value=0)
avg_tot = piv_df[['TOTAL_SERVICE_TIME', 'TOTAL_WAIT_TIME']].add_prefix("AVG_")
avg_pct1 = piv_df['IS_EVALUATED'].mul(100).astype(int)
avg_pct2 = piv_df['IS_NEGATIVE_GRADE'].mul(100).astype(int)
fresult = avg_tot.join(avg_pct1.to_frame("AVG_PERCENT_EVAL_1")).join(avg_pct2.to_frame("AVG_PERCENT_NEGATIVE")).reset_index()

fresult
```

[image]